# Using Couchbase Lite (not Couchbase Server) in a Golang application

Tags: go, couchbase-lite, cgo

I'm wondering if anyone has ever tried to use Couchbase Lite (not Couchbase Server) in a Golang application. In other words building it into a Golang binary?

I came across this library [Couchbase Lite Core](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-core) and through a quick read, it looks like the underlying library for Couchbase Lite (I stand corrected)? What I couldn't find though was how to use it.

Has anyone tried to make this work with something like `cgo` perhaps? I'm looking to build it statically into the application so it doesn't have dependencies when distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lite Core is the underlying implementation of the upcoming 2.0 version of Couchbase Lite.  It's still under development.  The intention is to have a common core, with platform and language specific bindings on top.

There is currently no Go implementation I'm aware of.  `cgo` does look like an option.  Given the goal of Lite Core being the underlying implementation for all platforms, this seems on its face like a reasonable approach.

If you're interested, there's a GitHub account for community projects at https://github.com/couchbaselabs.  If you work on this, it would be great to have it included there.

To see an example of platform integration, take a look at https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/tree/feature/2.0

Comment: It looks like there is no Go implementation yet, so I will mark this as the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried embedding Couchbase Lite, but my team and I make extensive use of embedded datastores like [BoltDB](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) Assuming you aren't using Couchbase's replication features heavily, BoltDB may meet your requirements.

Comment: Actually, the replication stuff is the reason I'm considering it.

Comment: I've found BoltDB quite unbearable due the transaction locks/deadlocks.